# how do I get the subtrees of dendrogram made by scipy.cluster.hierarchy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I had a confusion regarding this module (scipy.cluster.hierarchy) ... and still have some !

For example we have the following dendrogram:

[image: hierarchical clustering]

My question is how can I extract the coloured subtrees (each one represent a cluster) in a nice format, say SIF format ?
Now the code to get the plot above is:

```
import scipy
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

scipy.randn(100,2)

d = sch.distance.pdist(X)

Z= sch.linkage(d,method='complete')

P =sch.dendrogram(Z)

plt.savefig('plot_dendrogram.png')

T = sch.fcluster(Z, 0.5*d.max(), 'distance')
#array([4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 2,
#       3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4,
#       2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2,
#       4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2,
#       5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4], dtype=int32)

sch.leaders(Z,T)
# (array([190, 191, 182, 193, 194], dtype=int32),
#  array([2, 3, 1, 4,5],dtype=int32))
```

So now, the output of `fcluster()` gives the clustering of the nodes (by their id's), and `leaders()` described [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.leaders.html) is supposed to return 2 arrays:

- first one contains the leader nodes of the clusters generated by Z, here we can see we have 5 clusters, as well as in the plot
- and the second one the id's of these clusters

So if this leaders() returns resp. L and M : `L[2]=182` and `M[2]=1`, then cluster 1 is leaded by node id 182, which doesn't exist in the observations set X, the documentation says "... then it corresponds to a non-singleton cluster". But I can't get it ...

Also, I converted the Z to a tree by `sch.to_tree(Z)`, that will return an easy-to-use tree object, which I want to visualize, but which tool should I use as a graphical platform that manipulate these kind of tree objects as inputs?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering the part of your question regarding tree manipulation...

As explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11917779/832621), you can read the coordinates of the branches reading `icoord` and `dcoord` from the tree object. For each branch the coordinated are given from the left to the right.

If you want to manually plot the tree you can use something like:

```
def plot_tree(P, pos=None):
    plt.clf()
    icoord = scipy.array(P['icoord'])
    dcoord = scipy.array(P['dcoord'])
    color_list = scipy.array(P['color_list'])
    xmin, xmax = icoord.min(), icoord.max()
    ymin, ymax = dcoord.min(), dcoord.max()
    if pos:
        icoord = icoord[pos]
        dcoord = dcoord[pos]
        color_list = color_list[pos]
    for xs, ys, color in zip(icoord, dcoord, color_list):
        plt.plot(xs, ys, color)
    plt.xlim(xmin-10, xmax + 0.1*abs(xmax))
    plt.ylim(ymin, ymax + 0.1*abs(ymax))
    plt.show()
```

Where, in your code, `plot_tree(P)` gives:

[image]

The function allows you to select just some branches:

```
plot_tree(P, range(10))
```

[image]

Now you have to know which branches to plot. Maybe the `fcluster()` output is a little obscure and another way to find which branches to plot based on a minimum and a maximum distance tolerance would be using the output of `linkage()` directly (`Z` in the OP's case):

```
dmin = 0.2
dmax = 0.3
pos = scipy.all( (Z[:,2] >= dmin, Z[:,2] <= dmax), axis=0 ).nonzero()
plot_tree( P, pos )
```

Recommended references:

- [How does condensed distance matrix work? (pdist)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13079563/832621)
- [how to plot and annotate hierarchical clustering dendrograms in scipy/matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11917779/832621)

Comment: This answer helped me get to where I could plot subtrees of the dendrogram with observations found within a given phenetic distance (PD). I did not find the fcluster or fclusterdata  methods useful for this. I used sch.to_tree(linkage).pre_order(), then sequentially tested adjacent items in that list for being within the PD by reference to the pdist distance matrix (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17870926/1876324), then recalculated distance, linkage, and dendrogram for each group I wanted to plot. A PD of 4, for instance, would group the OP data into the desired 3 subtrees.

Comment: Just a note that I needed to call plt.clf() before the meat of the plot_tree function, otherwise the full dendrogram was shown.