# Interpreting the output of SciPy's hierarchical clustering dendrogram? (maybe found a bug...)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to figure out how the output of `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram` works... I thought I knew how it worked and I was able to use the output to reconstruct the dendrogram but it seems as if I am not understanding it anymore or there is a bug in `Python 3`'s version of this module.

This answer, [how do I get the subtrees of dendrogram made by scipy.cluster.hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883412/how-do-i-get-the-subtrees-of-dendrogram-made-by-scipy-cluster-hierarchy), implies that the `dendrogram` output dictionary gives `dict_keys(['icoord', 'ivl', 'color_list', 'leaves', 'dcoord'])` w/ all of the same size so you can `zip` them and `plt.plot` them to reconstruct the dendrogram.

Seems simple enough and I did get it work back when I used `Python 2.7.11` but once I upgraded to `Python 3.5.1` my old scripts weren't giving me the same results.

I started reworking my clusters for a very simple repeatable example and think I may have found a bug in Python 3.5.1's version of `SciPy version 0.17.1-np110py35_1`.  Going to use the `Scikit-learn` datasets b/c most people have that module from the conda distribution.

**Why aren't these lining up and how come I am unable to reconstruct the dendrogram in this way?**

```
# Init
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

# Load data
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

# Clustering
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, fcluster, leaves_list
from scipy.spatial import distance
from fastcluster import linkage # You can use SciPy one too

%matplotlib inline

# Dataset
A_data = load_diabetes().data
DF_diabetes = pd.DataFrame(A_data, columns = ["attr_%d" % j for j in range(A_data.shape[1])])

# Absolute value of correlation matrix, then subtract from 1 for disimilarity
DF_dism = 1 - np.abs(DF_diabetes.corr())

# Compute average linkage
A_dist = distance.squareform(DF_dism.as_matrix())
Z = linkage(A_dist,method="average")

# I modded the SO code from the above answer for the plot function
def plot_tree( D_dendro, ax ):
    # Set up plotting data
    leaves = D_dendro["ivl"]
    icoord = np.array( D_dendro['icoord'] )
    dcoord = np.array( D_dendro['dcoord'] )
    color_list = D_dendro["color_list"]

    # Plot colors
    for leaf, xs, ys, color in zip(leaves, icoord, dcoord, color_list):
        print(leaf, xs, ys, color, sep="\t")
        plt.plot(xs, ys,  color)

    # Set min/max of plots
    xmin, xmax = icoord.min(), icoord.max()
    ymin, ymax = dcoord.min(), dcoord.max()

    plt.xlim( xmin-10, xmax + 0.1*abs(xmax) )
    plt.ylim( ymin, ymax + 0.1*abs(ymax) )

    # Set up ticks
    ax.set_xticks( np.arange(5, len(leaves) * 10 + 5, 10))
    ax.set_xticklabels(leaves, fontsize=10, rotation=45)

    plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
D1 = dendrogram(Z=Z, labels=DF_dism.index, color_threshold=None, no_plot=True)
plot_tree(D_dendro=D1, ax=ax)
```

[image]

```
attr_1  [ 15.  15.  25.  25.]   [ 0.          0.10333704  0.10333704  0.        ]   g
attr_4  [ 55.  55.  65.  65.]   [ 0.          0.26150727  0.26150727  0.        ]   r
attr_5  [ 45.  45.  60.  60.]   [ 0.          0.4917828   0.4917828   0.26150727]   r
attr_2  [ 35.   35.   52.5  52.5]   [ 0.          0.59107459  0.59107459  0.4917828 ]   b
attr_8  [ 20.    20.    43.75  43.75]   [ 0.10333704  0.65064998  0.65064998  0.59107459]   b
attr_6  [ 85.  85.  95.  95.]   [ 0.          0.60957062  0.60957062  0.        ]   b
attr_7  [ 75.  75.  90.  90.]   [ 0.          0.68142114  0.68142114  0.60957062]   b
attr_0  [ 31.875  31.875  82.5    82.5  ]   [ 0.65064998  0.72066112  0.72066112  0.68142114]   b
attr_3  [  5.       5.      57.1875  57.1875]   [ 0.          0.80554653  0.80554653  0.72066112]   b
```

Here's one w/o the labels and just the `icoord` values for the x-axis
[image]

So check out the colors aren't mapping correctly. It says `[ 15.  15.  25.  25.]` for the `icoord` goes with `attr_1` but based on the values it looks like it goes with `attr_4`. Also, it doesn't go to all the way to the last leaf (`attr_9`) and that's b/c the length of `icoord` and `dcoord` is 1 less than the amount of `ivl` labels.

```
print([len(x) for x in [leaves, icoord, dcoord, color_list]]) 
#[10, 9, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`icoord`, `dcoord` and `color_list` describe the *links*, not the leaves.  `icoord` and `dcoord` give the coordinates of the "arches" (i.e. upside-down U or J shapes) for each link in a plot, and `color_list` is the color of those arches.  In a full plot, the length of `icoord`, etc., will be one less than the length of `ivl`, as you have observed.

Don't try to line up the `ivl` list with the `icoord`, `dcoord` and `color_list` lists. They are associated with different things.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial that either explains how to reconstruct the `dendrogram plot` with the `dendrogram's output dictionary` and a `custom color dictionary` or using the `link_color_func` with that color dictionary where {key = leaf: value = color}`? There are a few tutorials going around with the above method and I think a canonical answer would be good for the community.