# Annotating Dendrogram nodes in Scipy/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm trying to label the nodes in a dendrogram produced by `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram`.

I'm working with the [augmented dendrogram suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311782/3915498), trying to replace  the inter-cluster distance labels (1.01,1.57) in the example by strings such as ('a+c','a+b+c').

An example linkage matrix is below

```
Z = array([[ 2,  7,  0,  2],
           [ 0,  9,  0,  2],
           [ 1,  6,  0,  2],
           [ 5, 10,  0,  3],
           [11, 12,  0,  4],
           [ 4,  8,  0,  2],
           [14, 15,  0,  6],
           [13, 16,  0,  9],
           [ 3, 17,  1, 10]])
```

For this example I created temporary labels as follows :

`labels = [str(Z[ind,0].astype(int))+'+'+str(Z[ind,1].astype(int)) for ind in range(len(Z))]`

And modified the augmented_dendrogram to:

```
def augmented_dendrogram(labels,*args, **kwargs):
    ddata = cl.dendrogram(*args, **kwargs)
    if not kwargs.get('no_plot', False):
        for ind,(i, d) in enumerate(zip(ddata['icoord'], ddata['dcoord'])):
            x = 0.5 * sum(i[1:3])
            y = d[1]
            plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
            plt.annotate(labels[ind], (x, y), xytext=(10,15),
                         textcoords='offset points',
                         va='top', ha='center')
return ddata
```

However, the resulting labels are not aligned with the nodes in the dendrogram:

[image]

How can I align the labels to the correct node?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I found when working on a similar problem. Note that the linkage matrix given in the OP lacks the distances (the third column). I insert these distances artificially and then use them to identify the correct indices of the nodes in the dendrogram. The scipy `distance` function produces linkage matrix with distances already ordered (at least when using `ward` as the linking method).

Here is my code:

```
    Z = np.array([[ 2,  7,  0,  2],
           [ 0,  9,  0,  2],
           [ 1,  6,  0,  2],
           [ 5, 10,  0,  3],
           [11, 12,  0,  4],
           [ 4,  8,  0,  2],
           [14, 15,  0,  6],
           [13, 16,  0,  9],
           [ 3, 17,  1, 10]], dtype=float)

    Z[:, 2] = np.arange(1., len(Z)+1)
    labels = [str(len(Z)+1+ind)+'='+str(Z[ind,0].astype(int))+'+'+str(Z[ind,1].astype(int)) for ind in range(len(Z))]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
    dn = dendrogram(Z, ax=ax)
    ii = np.argsort(np.array(dn['dcoord'])[:, 1])
    for j, (icoord, dcoord) in enumerate(zip(dn['icoord'], dn['dcoord'])):
        x = 0.5 * sum(icoord[1:3])
        y = dcoord[1]
        ind = np.nonzero(ii == j)[0][0]
        ax.annotate(labels[ind], (x,y), va='top', ha='center')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('./tmp.png')
    plt.close(fig)
```

The result is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you're looking for the field `'leaves'` within the dictionary returned by scipy's `dendrogram` function. As per scipy's [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html):

> For each i, H[i] == j, cluster node j appears in position i in the left-to-right traversal of the leaves, where  and . If j is less than n, the i-th leaf node corresponds to an original observation. Otherwise, it corresponds to a non-singleton cluster.

In plain English, that means you can use this field to sort your labels into the correct order, e.g. by changing the corresponding line to:

```
plt.annotate(labels[ddata['leaves'][ind]], (x, y), xytext=(10,15), textcoords='offset points', va='top', ha='center')
```

Comment: As far as I can judge, this solution doesn't work, since `ddata['leaves']` includes only the leaves (i.e., only the terminal, but not the inner nodes).