# Relation between dendrogram plot coordinates and ClusterNodes in scipy

Tags: plot, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, linkage, dendrogram

I'm looking for a way to get the coordinates of a cluster point in the [dendrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) plot based on its [ClusterNode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ClusterNode.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ClusterNode) return by [to_tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.to_tree.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.to_tree).

Using scipy to build a dendogram from data such as:

```
X = data
Y = pdist(X)
Z = linkage(Y)
dend = dendrogram(Z)
rootnode, nodesList = to_tree(Z, rd=True)
```

What I would like to do is build a function `get_coords(somClusterNode)` that would return the tuple `(x, y)` specifying the position of the node in the plot.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311782/1565438), I managed to figure out how to get the position from the dendrogram return values, such as:

```
i, d = list(zip(dend['icoord'], dend['dcoord']))[-1]
x = 0.5 * sum(i[1:3])
y = d[1]
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
```

But I can figure out a relation between the nodesList ordering and the `icoord/dcoord` ordering in order to map one to the other.

Do you have any idea where I could look for ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What version of scipy are you using? When I try to run your code I get an error: `ValueError: Valid methods when the raw observations are omitted are 'single', 'complete', 'weighted', and 'average'.` Are you sure that line 3 should not be `Z = linkage(X, method="ward")`?

Comment: I use SciPy v.0.19.0 with python v.3.5.2

Comment: It seems that both are compatible : "The input y may be either a 1d compressed distance matrix or a 2d array of observation vectors." in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage

Comment: Yeah, but if you specify method="ward", my version will only work when providing the original observations. Upgrading my scipy installation to see if the issue persists...

Comment: ok. Then any method will do fine. I don't think my question depend on the linkage method I've chosen. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, but I couldn't get your code to run. Was just a version issue. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each dendrogram maps to only one tree of ClusterNodes, but any tree of ClusterNodes could map to an infinite number of dendrograms. Hence your mapping from node ID to (x,y) positions should probably just be another field in your dendrogram data structure instead of being a function of a ClusterNode. Instead of defining a function `get_coords`, I hence appends a dictionary to `dend` that maps node IDs to (x,y) coordinates. You can access the positions with

```
x,y = dend['node_id_to_coord'][node_id] # node_id is an integer as returned by ClusterNode.id
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram, to_tree
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# create some random data
X = np.random.rand(10, 3)

# get dendrogram
Z = linkage(pdist(X), method="ward")
dend = dendrogram(Z)

# ----------------------------------------
# get leave coordinates, which are at y == 0

def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
X = flatten(dend['icoord'])
Y = flatten(dend['dcoord'])
leave_coords = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(X,Y) if y==0]

# in the dendogram data structure,
# leave ids are listed in ascending order according to their x-coordinate
order = np.argsort([x for x,y in leave_coords])
id_to_coord = dict(zip(dend['leaves'], [leave_coords[idx] for idx in order])) # <- main data structure

# ----------------------------------------
# get coordinates of other nodes

# this should work but doesn't:

# # traverse tree from leaves upwards and populate mapping ID -> (x,y);
# # use linkage matrix to traverse the tree optimally
# # (each row in the linkage matrix corresponds to a row in dend['icoord'] and dend['dcoord'])
# root_node, node_list = to_tree(Z, rd=True)
# for ii, (X, Y) in enumerate(zip(dend['icoord'], dend['dcoord'])):
#     x = (X[1] + X[2]) / 2
#     y = Y[1] # or Y[2]
#     node_id = ii + len(dend['leaves'])
#     id_to_coord[node_id] = (x, y)

# so we need to do it the hard way:

# map endpoint of each link to coordinates of parent node
children_to_parent_coords = dict()
for i, d in zip(dend['icoord'], dend['dcoord']):
    x = (i[1] + i[2]) / 2
    y = d[1] # or d[2]
    parent_coord = (x, y)
    left_coord = (i[0], d[0])
    right_coord = (i[-1], d[-1])
    children_to_parent_coords[(left_coord, right_coord)] = parent_coord

# traverse tree from leaves upwards and populate mapping ID -> (x,y)
root_node, node_list = to_tree(Z, rd=True)
ids_left = range(len(dend['leaves']), len(node_list))

while len(ids_left) > 0:

    for ii, node_id in enumerate(ids_left):
        node = node_list[node_id]
        if (node.left.id in id_to_coord) and (node.right.id in id_to_coord):
            left_coord = id_to_coord[node.left.id]
            right_coord = id_to_coord[node.right.id]
            id_to_coord[node_id] = children_to_parent_coords[(left_coord, right_coord)]

    ids_left = [node_id for node_id in range(len(node_list)) if not node_id in id_to_coord]

# plot result on top of dendrogram
ax = plt.gca()
for node_id, (x, y) in id_to_coord.iteritems():
    if not node_list[node_id].is_leaf():
        ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
        ax.annotate(str(node_id), (x, y), xytext=(0, -8),
                    textcoords='offset points',
                    va='top', ha='center')

dend['node_id_to_coord'] = id_to_coord
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! It was days I was trying to solve this ! Ty, ty, ty !

Comment: I tried to edit to change `.iteritems()` to `.items()` to make it compatible with python3 however, stack doesn't allow edit inferior to 6 characters.

Comment: My pleasure. I will make the edit in a second. Also, I just figured out that I could use the linkage matrix to traverse the tree more effectively. Edit incoming.

Comment: Ok, this version is much simpler now. I somehow hadn't realised that each link in the linkage matrix corresponds to the `dendrogram['icoord']` and `dendrogram['dcoords']`.

Comment: I just figured out that the new version place the point in the wrong place (I can't figure out why...). Rolling back to the first version works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the node IDs sometimes end up in all the wrong places. I will roll back, too.

Comment: `while len(ids_left) > 0:`                                                                                  `ids_left = [node_id for node_id in range(len(node_list)) if not node_id in id_to_coord]`                                                                                                                                          This two line of code created trouble for me when I tried running them on my truncated dendogram. By omitting this two line, this code served my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it:

The ids of the dendogram appear to be generated by a reversed right to left traversal of the tree. This allows us to construct a translation from `node.id` to the index of `icoord` and `dcoord` as follows:

```py
def rl_traversal(node):
    # skipping leaves
    if not node.is_leaf():
        yield node.id
        yield from rl_traversal(node.right)
        yield from rl_traversal(node.left)

id_map = dict(zip( rl_traversal(root), reversed(range(root.get_count()-1))) ))
# id_map[node_id] = dendogram_id
```

The coordinates of a node can then be obtained via `dendo['icoord'][id_map[node_id]]`